# AppFabric Caching transport security

Tags: security, communication, appfabric, transport

I'd like to understand how security works in Windows Server AppFabric Cache. If i have it defined like

```
<securityProperties mode="Transport" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
```

how does it encrypt the communication? Is it SSL? If it is how do i configure which certificate to use? Does AppFabric Cache utilize WCF internally or use some custom protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppFabric Caching uses Windows identity information for all encryption/signing. Specifically, whatever Windows identity your cache client process is running as when it communicates with the cache server.

It's the same as if you were using raw WCF and applied the [`WindowsStreamSecurityBindingElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.windowsstreamsecuritybindingelement.aspx) with a corresponding [`ProtectionLevel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.protectionlevel.aspx).